# MySQL Event Error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create an event that adds recurring payments to a payment table every day at 3PM. payment.day is an integer that represents the day number. This is what I have:

```
CREATE EVENT add_recurring
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2015-16-04 15:00:00'
DO INSERT INTO payment (amount, note, custID, type) SELECT amount, note, custID, 'C' FROM recurring WHERE day = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), %e)
```

I am getting the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%e)' at line 4

Can anyone see the error and explain to me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format should be a string:

```
CREATE EVENT add_recurring
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2015-16-04 15:00:00'
DO INSERT INTO payment (amount, note, custID, type) SELECT amount, note, custID, 'C' FROM recurring WHERE day = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%e')
```

Source: [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

Add %e in quotes. As any format must be supplied in single quotes.  So change %e to '%e'